При наведении на метку отображается некорректная надпись с адресом и телефоном на английском
Подключили яндекс-карты к сайту на базе Тильда. Карта отображается корректно с меткой. Но при наведении на метку, отображается некорректная надпись с адресом и телефоном на английском.
Marrakech Mixture Salon Ltd56 Chambers St, New York, NY 10007, USAPhone: +12126789012Email: enquiry@lessalon.com
The salon is open daily, 11 AM till 10 PM. Feel free to drop by — we'd be happy to advise you on cosmetology and beauty.
Хотя мы находимся в РБ, г.Брест..
Как исправить?

Скорее всего, в этом месте на карте яндекса находится точка с ошибочными данными. Например, здесь https://yandex.ru/maps/?ll=0.000000%2C0.000000&z=19 , в океане находится автобусная остановка.

Спасибо, похоже так и есть)

Похоже на текст-рыбу от Тильды. Посмотрите внимательно в настройках блока – там должны быть поля для ввода текста вместо филлеров, которые вам предлагает Тильда.
Балун создаётся Тильдой и настраивается Тильдой. На скриншотах пример ситуации, когда точка находится в Краснодаре, но описание не соответствует точке. Нужно задать нужную информацию в поле "Контент".

